# JavaScript what can go inside ev.dataTransfer.setData(..., ....);

Tags: javascript

I have been building my first drag and drop pages using code from W3Schools suitably tweaked. At least I think it's suitable. You can see the full code at [this page](https://tacheiru.us/hopefulviper/omophoita/muslin_anthony4.html). Just view source. The lines of code need to be on top of the page, because I also load copies into my institution's course management system and the scripts won't work there if it's on a separate page.

I noticed when I was making the script that W3schools had

ev.dataTransfer.setData(text,  ev.target.id);

I, however, was moving images (seven to nine of them). Images, I reasoned were not text. I substituted a variable for text.

ev.dataTransfer.setData(flying1piece, ev.target.id);

My program works, but I wonder:

*What else, if anything else, can go inside those (parentheses) besides text or a variable?
*Will text work for an image?
*Is there any substitute for ev.target.id, for example another variable?

Drag and drops are not in the two books I am using to learn JavaScript, so my knowledge for drag and drops is really piece meal. W3Schools also did not explain ev.dataTransfer the way it explains CSS elements, with all the options. I am the only librarian on several campuses at my institution who "knows" JavaScript, so I am my own support. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: See [the MDN page for `setData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData).